# Invalid qualifier error when deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro that is running into an error

> Invalid qualifier

pointing to the i variable.

```vb
Sub Macro6()

Dim last As Long
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    For i = last To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value Like "X" Then
            .Cells(i.End(xlDown), 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

This macro is supposed to identify cell with value "X" (that will be located at the end of column A) and then delete all rows below that are empty.

Comment: `i` is a `Long`. You can't use `.End(xlDown)` on a `Long`. `.End` is the property of a `Range`.

Comment: Btw, `last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row` should be `last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @BigBen I can't simply change i as `long` to `range`, right? Do you have any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Is your goal just to delete rows in column A that are blank?

Comment: @BigBen My goal is to delete all rows below a cell that has value "X" and the row cell "X" itself in column A.

Comment: I guess said another way, what rows do you want to keep?

Comment: @BigBen all rows above cell "X".

Comment: Are there several cells in column `A` containing `X`? If so, which one is it? The first or the last? Are we looking just for `X` or `*X*` or...? Is the search case-sensitive i.e. `x <> X`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 There will be just one cell with value `X` at the column bottom. The seach is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you skip the loop, and use `Range.Find` instead.

```
Sub DeleteAllAfterX()
   With ActiveSheet
       Dim rng As Range
       Set rng = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="X", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

       If Not rng Is Nothing Then
           .Rows(rng.Row & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
       End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Delete Below String

**`Application.Match`**

- If you are expecting one occurrence of the string or you're after the first occurrence, then the safer and more efficient choice is using `Application.Match`.

```vb
Sub DeleteBelowFirst()
    ' Uses 'Application.Match'.

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False (optionally)
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    DeleteBelowFirstString rg, 1, "x" ' , True ' True would keep the found row

End Sub

Sub DeleteBelowFirstString( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal ColumnIndex As Long, _
        ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
        Optional ByVal ExcludeFoundRow As Boolean = False)
    ' If the worksheet is filtered, only the filtered (visible) rows will be deleted.
    Const ProcName As String = "DeleteBelowFirstString"
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(ColumnIndex)
    
    Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(CriteriaString, crg, 0)
    If IsError(rIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Value not found.", vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = rIndex - 1
    
    If ExcludeFoundRow Then
        rOffset = rOffset + 1
        If rCount = rOffset Then
            MsgBox "There's nothing below.", vbExclamation, ProcName
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rCount - rOffset).Offset(rOffset)
    Debug.Print ProcName & ": " & drg.Address & " deleted."
    
    drg.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

**`Range.Find`**

- If you're after the last occurrence, then `Application.Match` does not work and you could e.g. use `Range.Find` with its limitations. It will also work for a single occurrence.

```vb
Sub DeleteBelowLast()
    ' Uses 'Range.Find'.

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False (mandatory)
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    DeleteBelowLastString rg, 1, "x" ' , True ' True would keep the found row

End Sub

Sub DeleteBelowLastString( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal ColumnIndex As Long, _
        ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
        Optional ByVal ExcludeFoundRow As Boolean = False)
    ' Make sure the worksheet is not filtered or the Find method will fail.
    Const ProcName As String = "DeleteBelowLastString"
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(ColumnIndex)
    
    ' If the column contains formulas, instead of 'xlFormulas', use 'xlValues'
    ' and additionally make sure that no rows are hidden
    ' or the Find method will fail (hidden rows don't affect 'xlFormulas').
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = crg.Find( _
        What:=CriteriaString, After:=crg.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) ' last occurrence
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value not found.", vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = fCell.Row - rg.Row
    
    If ExcludeFoundRow Then
        rOffset = rOffset + 1
        If rCount = rOffset Then
            MsgBox "There's nothing below.", vbExclamation, ProcName
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rCount - rOffset).Offset(rOffset)
    Debug.Print ProcName & ": " & drg.Address & " deleted."
    
    drg.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

- Note that both methods support wild characters.